# Why doesn't this broadcast receiver work in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this broadcast receiver declared in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="classes.VoiceLaunchReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My receiver Class:

```
public class VoiceLaunchReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {     
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, VoiceLaunchService.class);
     //   service.putExtra(action, true);
        Log.i("joscsr","Incoming Voice Launch Broadcast...");  

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.e("joshcsr", "***********\nCSR Resumed (BC)\n************");
            ctx.startService(service);
            }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.e("joshcsr", "***********\nCSR STOPPED by SCREEN (BC)\n************");
            ctx.stopService(service);
            }
        }
}
```

I registered the SCREEN_OFF intent in the onCreate method of a service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Register screen OFF BroadCast
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(speechBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
```

It does its thing whenever the user unblocks and turns on the screen. It works perfectly in Jellybean 4.3 and lower: my Logcats inside my Broadcast receiver are shown whenever the screen is locked pr unlocked.
Why won't this exact code won't work in Lollipop? Are there new Intents that I must listen to instead?

(I already know that the systems send that intent, what I want is to detect it with my receiver)

Comment: post ur java code too

Comment: wont work? what shown in your logcat?

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Hi guys, I added the broadcast receiver's code and the register code for the Screen_OFF intent. You can see the logcats I am trying to show in Lollipop.

Comment: ACTION_SCREEN_OFF only works WHILE service is still running. Check if your service gets killed or something.

Comment: @velis I see your point, but Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT is not caught in the first place.

Comment: Just to try it: I have android.intent.action.ACTION_USER_PRESENT (note the additional "ACTION_") in my manifest. Sometimes I don't know which of these constants is the correct one :(

Comment: @velis Sorry, it did not work :( I saw a clue on the logcat that may hint a solution, because I now that Screen Lock security is tighter in lollipop. The intent is sent by the system, but it seems something is missing to capture it:  UserPresentBroadcastReceiver(2446): Received Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x24000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.trustagent.UserPresentBroadcastReceiver }.

Comment: Ok, after much struggling, I found a solution to this problem, see the answer below.

Comment: Same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081414/why-wont-this-broadcast-receiver-work-in-lollipop

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it (tested on 4.3 and 5.1). I was able to declare `"android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"` inside the manifest, as long as you have the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, it is OK!! My mini app consists of a Broadcast receiver that reacts to the screen ON/OFF state, and runs a background service that does continuous voice recognition. If the screen is off, the recognition is turned off.

**Here is the code, enjoy: MANIFEST:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> <receiver android:name="classes.VoiceLaunchReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**BROADCAST RECEIVER:**

```
public class VoiceLaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {     
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, VoiceLaunchService.class);
     //   service.putExtra(action, true);
        Log.i("joscsr","Incoming Voice Launch Broadcast...");  

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.i("joshcsr", "************\nCSR Resumed (BC)\n************");
            ctx.startService(service);
            }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("joshcsr", "************\nCSR STOPPED by SCREEN (BC)\n************");
            ctx.stopService(service);  
            }
        }  
}
```

As you can imagine, my `USER_PRESENT` broadcast receiver is not registered anywhere else. I do register `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and ON in the `onCreate` method of my service, who was triggered by my receiver.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Register screen ON/OFF BroadCast
    launcher=new VoiceLaunchReceiver();
    IntentFilter i=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);               
    registerReceiver(launcher,i);
    Log.d("joshcsr","VoiceLaunch Service CREATED"); 
    }
```

Finally I unregister the screen on/off in the `onDestroy()` of my service:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(launcher);}
```

Comment: I did not need the permission nor the category. I had to remove `exported="false"` from the receiver though. Tested on stock Android 5

Comment: I did not add exported=false to begin with... @OneWorld